# Push on a git server pending?

Tags: git, push

I just set up a git server. I have a repository made with

```
git init --bare
```

named repo_equipe.git. I successfully cloned that repository on my computer remotely from the server with `git clone git://myserv/myrepo.git.`

Then, I added a file and locally commited it. But when I try to push it with

```
git push origin master OR git push
```

This is pending ! On my serveur I have a daemon launched with :

```
git daemon --base-path=C:/git --verbose --enable=receive-pack --export-all
```

This is doing nothing, juste waiting on both sides. 
The last line on my server is : Request receive-pack for '/repo_equipe.git'
The last line on my client is the command git push.

Thanks a lot for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

tried `git push origin BARE:master`
Nothing.

It's just waiting from both sides ; have no clue why this isn't working.